# Stored Procedure/Cursor Logic

Tags: mysql

I've designed a stored procedure that uses two cursors to update a total_sal column in department based on employee's that belong to that department.

I am not getting the correct results and I believe I may have a wrong idea on the flow of a stored procedure and cursor.

The logic I am trying to use to accomplish this:

1- open Cursor to iterate through department

2- at each row in department get the department number

3- open Cursor to iterate through employee

4- at each employee, if employee dept number is equal to the department number from the dept curser, we add their salary to a total_sum

5- after employee table has been exhausted we finally update the department's total_salary with the total_sum

6 - restart at step 2

Here is the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE updateSalary()
BEGIN
  DECLARE emp_sal, eDno, dDno INT;  
  DECLARE total_sum INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE finished INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE dep_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT Dno FROM Department;
  DECLARE emp_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT Dno, Salary FROM Employee;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1;

  open dep_cursor;
  department_loop: LOOP
    FETCH dep_cursor INTO dDno;
    IF finished = 1 THEN
      LEAVE department_loop;
    END IF;

    open emp_cursor;

    employee_loop: LOOP
      FETCH emp_cursor INTO eDno, emp_sal;
      IF eDno = dDno THEN
        SET total_sum = total_sum + emp_sal;
      END IF;
      IF finished = 1 THEN
        update department SET total_sal = total_sum WHERE department.dno = dDno;
        LEAVE employee_loop;
      END IF;
      SET total_sum = 0;
    END LOOP employee_loop;
    close emp_cursor;
  END LOOP department_loop;
  CLOSE dep_cursor;
END;
/
```

Here is the SQLFiddle I've been working with, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b9cc2f/1/1

I'm not very familiar with debugging MySQL, if this were Java I would just throw in some print statements to see what's going on.

Comment: Using a stored procedure, you need to call it every time a department is changed on a record. Instead use triggers that causes auto update of total_sal value in dept table.

Comment: @Ravinder this is an assignment where I am required to use a stored procedure and cursors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see some logical errors in your stored procedure. It is due to improper handling of `cursor` finished `fetch` state.

As you mentioned it is an assignment on cursors, I suggest you some steps to follow that will perform desired action.

1. Declare a cursor on employee with `dno` and sum of `salary` grouped by `dno`.
2. Open the same cursor and loop through
3. If not `finished` then, `update deparment` in a single statement with
   values fetched from above emp cursor. use `dno` fetched in `where` clause.
4. If finished then Close emp cursor
5. End procedure
6. Call procedure
7. Select all from department
       -- resultset shows: all happies